# Overriding setter method for attr_accessor when including InstanceMethods module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an `ActiveRecord` extension (abbreviated):

```
module HasPublishDates
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_publish_dates(*args)
      attr_accessor :never_expire

      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def never_expire=(value)
      @never_expire = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
    end

    def another_instance_method
      'something to return'
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  include HasPublishDates
end
```

which can be called like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_publish_dates
  ...
end
```

The idea is that `never_expire=` should override the setter defined by `attr_accessor :never_expire`. However, it doesn't seem to be working:

```
m = MyModel.new
m.never_expire            #=> nil
m.never_expire = '1'      #=> '1'
m.never_expire            #=> '1' should be true if never_expire= has been overridden
m.another_instance_method #=> 'something to return' works as expected
```

As you can see, `another_instance_method` is being included and is working as expected but `never_expire=` is not overriding the setter as I expected.

If I change HasPublishDates to use `class_eval` then it works as expected:

```
module HasPublishDates
  ...
  module ClassMethods
    def has_publish_dates(*args)
      ...
      class_eval do
        def never_expire=(value)
          @never_expire = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
        end

        def another_instance_method
          'something to return'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
...

m = MyModel.new
m.never_expire            #=> nil
m.never_expire = '1'      #=> true
m.never_expire            #=> true
m.another_instance_method #=> 'something to return'
```

I imagine that this is because `InstanceMethods` is defined before `attr_accessor :never_expire` is called by `has_publish_dates`.

Though I think that `class_eval` is an elegant way of doing things I also like the idea of having my instance methods exposed for documentation so there's no "magic" when another developer is trying to use my code.

Is there anyway I can use the `include InstanceMethods` approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call order in Ruby starts with normal instance methods before proceeding to methods of included modules and superclass methods. The `never_expire=` method created by `attr_accessor` winds up being an instance method, so it's called rather than the `InstanceMethods` module's method. If you use `attr_reader` instead, so that no `never_expire=` instance method gets defined, it will work as you intend.

That said, you're making things more complicated than they need to be with those extra ClassMethods and InstanceMethods modules. Just use modules like they were intended:

```
module HasPublishDates
  attr_reader :never_expire

  def never_expire=(value)
    @never_expire = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasPublishDates
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just not bother with the attr_accessor... after all, you'd just need to add:

```
def never_expire
  @never_expire
end
```

and it'd work just fine without that.

If it's an actual AR column on the db, though, I'd recommend using

```
set_attribute(:never_expire, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column....
```

rather than the @never_expire variable. You'd also not need the attr_accessor in that case.

A a final option, you could use class-eval *just* on the include statement eg:

```
module ClassMethods
  def has_publish_dates(*args)
    attr_accessor :never_expire

    class_eval do
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
```